# My php files can still write into the filesystem even though I've set the owner to a non root user

Tags: php, linux

Please bear with my stupid question since I'm still new in this php file permission thing, so I have changed the owner of my php files to `nobody`, they look like this:
[image]

But when I test writing a php file and execute a shell script, it can still write into the file system:

```
exec('echo "Hello World" > /etc/test.txt');
```

Here's the permissions of `/etc/`:
[image]

Here's the permissions of `php-cgi`:
[image]

I use `lighttpd` and here's the permission:
[image]

Here's the permission of `/`:
[image]
And lastly this is my `php.ini` configuration: http://pastebin.com/5t5LRY1a

I don't want my php files to be able to have full access to my filesystem. How can I solve this ?

Comment: I might be going in the wrong direction here, but what user is your apache/ngix/etc daemon running as?

Comment: Stop `chmod`ing things 777... Also check the user under which php runs.

Comment: @MarkPhillips It's owned by root, I've updated my post with the screenshot @PeeHaa if you  mean the php files they're owned by `nobody` check my post above

Comment: Also you haven't shown the directory permissions. Also this is not programming related.

Comment: @hillz no that is not what I meant. I woudl suggest hiring a system admin.

Comment: I don't want to hire a system admin since it's not a server in a big company, it's just my openwrt router that I use as a local webserver at home. I want to be able to fix it all by myself

Comment: @hillz there is no evidence above that your test.txt file was written to /etc.

Comment: @Progrock I can `cat` the file if you want proof, believe me it's written to `/etc/` I have seen the written file

Comment: Could it be openwrt's filesystem? Something like an overlay fs?  Check their docs/community.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that but this is what my filesystem looks like: https://s18.postimg.org/tcj9httl5/image.png

Comment: It might be worth adding a new user like www-user and ensuring apache runs as this user, running a web server (or any service really) as root is always a bad idea.

Then you can grant the user permissions to a  new group you create as well, then change the folder/file permissions of /www to suit the new group you have created.

Comment: If that's a shell script `exec('echo "Hello World" > /etc/test.txt');` won't that call PHP in CLI mode? If so, couldn't it potentially have a different user and php.ini (e.g. `php-cli.ini` will override default) to say PHP an an Apache module?

Comment: @CD001 it will belong to the user that ran the script.  Apache isn't being used it's lighthttpd.  Probably being ran as root, and hence has free range to the filesystem.  OP might want to find out how to run lighthttpd as another user (simple config options).  Hard to say without knowing set-up which could be quite esoteric as it's openwrt.  Don't know the ins and outs of filesystem and mounts.

Comment: If you run the following command as root `lsof -i:80` it should show which program and user is running your webserver, assuming that it's running on port 80.

Comment: @Progrock ... and if the shell script is being run as root then it *would* have permission to write to `/etc/` wouldn't it (755)?

Answer (score 0):

**Finally found the solution**:

I have to edit `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` and add these lines:

```
server.username = "www" 
server.groupname = "www"
```

Like what [this webpage](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/tutorialconfiguration) says:

> Now the web server is listening on port 80, the default for HTTP
>   traffic, and will switch to the user www and the group www. The server
>   has to be started as root to take control of port 80, but it's not
>   necessary or a good idea to continue running as root after port
>   acquisition, so the server switches to user www.